# returning promise from useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I was going through the article https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data.

It gives the below 2 snippets to demonstrate how to deal with promises in useEffect. The first one throws an error while to second one doesnt.

first snippet -

```
  useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await axios(
      'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux',
    );
 
    setData(result.data);
  }, []);
```

second snippet -

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux',
      );
 
      setData(result.data);
    };
 
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Why does the second not throw an error, when `fetchdata()` is called it will return a promise, and thus a promise will be returned from `useEffect` too. How is the second snippet different from the first one ?

Comment: `when fetchdata() is called it will return a promise, and thus a promise will be returned from useEffect too.` No.

Comment: What error does the first statement throw?

Comment: both returns `undefined`. A useEffect function simply cannot be `async`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only return **nothing** or a **cleanup function** for useEffect hook.
The reason the first snippet is throwing an error is because you marked the function async and the functions that are marked async will always return a promise.

```
//The function is marked async
 useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await axios(
      'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux',
    );
 
    setData(result.data);
  }, []);
```

It breaks the rule of returning either nothing or a cleanup function.

However In the second snippet, you are using useEffect function to call an async function, but since the useEffect function itself is not async, that means it is not returning a promise

```
//this is not marked async
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux',
      );
 
      setData(result.data);
    };
 
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what l know you cant use promise directly on React Hook. You can use it inside in function and it will work. Hooks are there so that you do not need to use classes in React.

More about Hooks => https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html